# How to set virtual server for Zend Framework?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, virtualhost

I am having trouble getting a virtual server up and running with ZEND.  I have followed the installer and set up a project in my C:/ drive.  However, the browser will not pick up the site.

I changed the appache config file to uncomment the following line.

> # Virtual hosts
>
> ```
>  Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
> ```

I changed the vhosts.conf file with the following code based on the quickstart information included on the zend website.  The project folders are located at C:\zendProject\quickstart\public

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName local
    DocumentRoot /zendProject/quickstart/public

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /zendProject/quickstart/public>
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

I then changed the hosts file to read with the following lines.

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1     local
>
> ::1             localhost

I then restarted the appache server using the vista services manager.  I checked the basic webpage for the ZEND control panel and this is working so the server is definately operational, but I get a message saying that the browser cannot connect to local.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I just looked through the error logs and found the following entry - not sure if this helps
[Sun Aug 19 12:05:38 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:8080 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: I have since found that if I use a custom port on ZEND i need to specify the port in the URL like this http:/local:8080 and it will work just fine. I hope others find this useful, but if anyone has a suggested workaround welcome any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pretty much use any port you want with a vhost just make sure you have a line like:
`NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere in the vhost document. This line specifies the port apache looks at for routing. Most of the prebuilt servers (WAMP, Xampp, Zend Server) will come with a  template `httpd-vhosts.conf` that usually includses this line. Sometimes it is still commented, either way make sure it is there and uncommented and reflects the port you want to use.

Also if you are using Zend Framework MVC projects in a vhost you want to ***FollowSymlinks***

Here is complete example of a working httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Zend\Apache2/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\www\home-local\public"
    ServerName home.local
    ErrorLog "E:\www\home-local\logs\error.log"
    <Directory "E:\www\home-local" >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the httpd-vhosts.conf provided Zend Server CE as modified for my dev environment.

*A few more notes.*

- If you wish to use the localhost, make sure you add it to your vhosts file and make it the **first** vhost
- if you have more then one directory that hosts sites you can put the directory definition in your vhost, in fact it's helpful to apply strict access to the top level directories and only loosen what you need to in the vhosts
- As always make sure you remember to make sure that mod_rewrite is uncommented: 
  `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
- Always restart Apache after making **any** changes to *httpd.conf* or *http-vhosts.conf*

Answer (score 0):

If port 80 isn't being used by anything other than Apache on your server, change `<VirtualHost *:8080>` to `<VirtualHost *:80>` and restart Apache.

You should then be able to access your vhost by navigating to `http://local`

There is no need to use port `8080` unless you are already running something on port 80.  If that were the case, then you have no choice but to include the `:8080` after the hostname when you access your site in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have set your port to 8080 , change that to *.80

Your configuration should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local
    DocumentRoot C:\zendProject\quickstart\public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>
```

In windows, the path starts with `C:\` and not `/`

Also have a look at this [start up tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/zend-framework-from-scratch/).